# Gruntjs: how to create a task to concatenate file based on their directory

Tags: templates, underscore.js, gruntjs

I've put up a task using gruntjs and grunt-contrib-jst to pre-compile all my template files (stored in the "coffee" folder) and concatenate them in a single javascript file, AppTemplate.js.

```
    jst: {
        compile: {
            options: {
              templateSettings: {
                "variable" : "data"
              },
              prettify: true,
              processName: function(filename) {
                return name = filename.replace('coffee/','');
              }
            },
            files: {
                "js/AppTemplates.js": ["coffee/**/*.html"]
            }
        }
    },
```

All is working good so far, anyway since the number of templates it's growing I want to split the templates in separated files grouped by the modules they belong.

My folder structure it's the following:

```
|--modules
  |--user
    |--templates
      * html template files *
    user_module.coffee
  |--post
    |--templates
      * html template files *
    post_module.coffee
```

and so on...

I just want to create a template.js files inside each templates folder, but I don't know how to edit my original task to achieve that. Any help or tips is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define each directory directly - something like:

```
files: { 
    'public/js/allfiles.js': [ 'public/js/*.js' ],
    'public/js/lib/allfiles.js': [ 'public/js/lib/*.js' ] 
}
```

Or you could do something a little more dynamic so that each new module directory is picked up automatically.

For example:

```
module.exports = function( grunt ) {
    "use strict";
    var util = require('util');
    var path = require('path');

    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON("package.json"),
        buildFiles: {},
        concat: {
            options: {
                separator: ';'
            },
            dist: {
                files: '<%= buildFiles %>'
            }
        },
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['buildList', 'concat']);

    grunt.registerTask('buildList', function() {
        var dirs = grunt.file.expand({filter: 'isDirectory'}, ['./public/js/**']);

        var files = grunt.config.data.buildFiles;
        dirs.forEach(function(val) {
            files[path.join(val, 'allfiles.js')] = [path.join(val, '*.js')];
        });
    });
};
```

This code basically just builds the same static configuration as the initial option.

Output:

```
Running "buildList" task

Running "concat:dist" (concat) task
File "public/js/allfiles.js" created.
File "public/js/lib/allfiles.js" created.
```

Note: there may be better ways to make use of grunts various file apis to do this...